# How to format strings using printf() to get equal length in the output

Tags: c, string, printf, pretty-print

I have two functions, one which produces messages like `Starting initialization...` and another which checks return codes and outputs `"Ok"`, `"Warning"` or `"Error"`. However, the output that is produced is of the different length:

```
Starting initialization...Ok.
Checking init scripts...Ok.
```

How can I get something like the following?

```
Starting initialization...       Ok.
Checking init scripts...         Ok.
```

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You can specify a width on string fields, e.g.

```
printf("%-20s", "initialization...");
```

And then whatever's printed with that field will be blank-padded to the width you indicate.

The `-` left-justifies your text in that field.

Comment: Alas, I'm not clever enough to count that high. However, I trust the asker to be intelligent enough to extrapolate from my example :)

Comment: what about right justified? There aren't any flags mentioned in K&R

Comment: Right justified is the default. Without a `-`, your data will be right justified in a field whose width you specified.

Answer (score 33):

Additionally, if you want the flexibility of choosing the `width`, you can choose between one of the following two formats (with or without truncation):

```
int width = 30;
// No truncation uses %-*s
printf( "%-*s %s\n", width, "Starting initialization...", "Ok." );
// Output is "Starting initialization...     Ok."

// Truncated to the specified width uses %-.*s
printf( "%-.*s %s\n", width, "Starting initialization...", "Ok." );
// Output is "Starting initialization... Ok."
```

Answer (score 30):

`printf` allows formatting with width specifiers. For example,

```
printf( "%-30s %s\n", "Starting initialization...", "Ok." );
```

You would use a negative width specifier to indicate left-justification because the default is to use right-justification.

Answer (score 16):

There's also the `%n` modifier which can help in certain circumstances. It returns the column on which the string was so far. Example: you want to write several rows that are within the width of the first row like a table.

```
int width1, width2;
int values[6][2];
printf("|%s%n|%s%n|\n", header1, &width1, header2, &width2);

for(i=0; i<6; i++)
   printf("|%*d|%*d|\n", width1, values[i][0], width2, values[i][1]);
```

will print two columns of the same width of whatever length the two strings `header1` and `header2` may have.
I don't know if all implementations have the `%n`, but [Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29) and Linux do.

Comment: This solution works, but anyone who takes this and puts it in their code should be aware of the [risk of introducing memory vulnerabilities](https://www.us-cert.gov/bsi/articles/knowledge/coding-practices/do-not-use-n-format-string-specifier).

Answer (score 1):

There's also the rather low-tech solution of counting adding spaces by hand to make your messages line up. Nothing prevents you from including a few trailing spaces in your message strings.

Answer (score -3):

Start with the use of *tabs* - the **\t** character modifier. It will advance to a fixed location (columns, terminal lingo).

However, it doesn't help if there are differences of more than the column width (4 characters, if I recall correctly).

To fix that, write your "OK/NOK" stuff using a fixed number of tabs (5? 6?, try it). Then return (**\r**) without new-lining, and write your message.

Comment: There's always the danger that a string is longer than a tab stop thereby forcing the resulting tab and text to be mis-aligned.

Comment: Not really... first write the tabbed OK/NOK, then /r, now write the phrase, now /n. The phrase could overwrite the OK/NOK.
But your way is way better, I didn't know about negative justification.