# How to make 2 outputs a certain distance appart regardless of size of first input?

Tags: c

Seems like a trivial question, but I can seem to figure it out. How to make 2 outputs a certain distance appart regardless of size of first input?

For example this is my current output:

```
Dell       $1200
Toshiba       $2000
Sony Vaio       $1000
```

The spaces are uneven when I print them out. I want the output to look like the following:

```
Dell       $1200
Toshiba    $2000
Sony Vaio  $1000
```

Basically I want the distance to be the same between the 2 outputs regardless of the size of the first input.

This is my code:

```
printf("\nEnter a laptops name: ");
scanf("%s", &laptopName);
printf("Enter its price: ");
scanf("%d", &laptopPrice);
printf("\n");

printf("%s     ", laptopName);
printf("$%d", laptopPrice);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - How to justify output lines using printf() to get equal length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809399/c-how-to-justify-output-lines-using-printf-to-get-equal-length)

Comment: Do what R Samuel Klatchko said, but if you want to be truly independent of input size, replace -20 with maximum input length. Just in case somebody writes "my super awesome no-brand low-cost computing machine". Or on the other hand...HP, ibm, dell... those would produce lost of emptiness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify a field width (negative value to left align):

```
printf("%-20s %d", laptopName, laptopPrice)
```

Comment: You have a gold badge for C, so why not just close it as a duplicate?

Comment: @jpw Thanks for making me look up "dupehammer" :)