# Making a text box in c++

Tags: c++

I'm programming some very simple stuff and I want to make a neat little "text box" at the beginning of my program in the command prompt with some basic info. An example of what I mean:

```
cout << "Creators: J. Adams & T. Jefferson" << endl; 
cout << "Nicknames: Johnnny & Tommy" << endl;
cout << "Age: 20 & 21" << endl;
cout << "This program is for ..... << endl;
```

This is just an example, and one of the things I'd like is a simple way to align these things (so that "Johnny" is directly below "J. Adams", or at least directly enough so you know they belong together). I know of setw but you have to include  for that, and I'd like a method where you don't have to use that.

Other than that, I'd like a simple way to put an outline around the text (that's what I mean by text "box"). Nothing to fancy, just something you can do with the first 128 normal characters. I've googled around for something similar to no avail.

Comment: `printf` is your friend here. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809399/c-how-to-justify-output-lines-using-printf-to-get-equal-length

Comment: Research your favorite C++ reference for "justification" and "setw".

Comment: You won't include `<iomanip>` for no particular reason? If you refuse to include any headers, you're not going to be able to use anything.

Comment: setw is part of the c++ standard, with the same reasoning you could refuse to include `<iostream>`.....