# Format a string into columns in C

Tags: c, string, printf, string-formatting

I have a problem with getting this string to even out nicely into columns despite what size each of the strings are.  I've tried different formatting and other stuff; it's just not working. The way the function works is that before the `printCompanyTable` works, there's another function that updates all the string variables you see below, so I'm guessing that's where the problem might be, I think.

```
int printCompanyInfo() {  // this will print out the format for as long as I need it.
    char discount[30];
    char tax[30];
    if (discountTypeLookup == 0) {
        strcpy_s(discount, 30, "Not Applicable");
    }
    else if (discountTypeLookup == 1) {
        strcpy_s(discount, 30, "before Tax");
    }
    else if (discountTypeLookup == 2) {
        strcpy_s(discount, 30, "After Tax");
    }
    else if (discountTypeLookup == 3) {
        strcpy_s(discount, 30, "Before Tax > 14,500");
    }
    if (payTaxLookup == 0) {
        strcpy_s(tax, 30, "No");
    }
    else if (payTaxLookup == 1) {
        strcpy_s(tax, 30, "Yes");
    }
    printf_s("%s %s %f %s %s %s\n", companyId, companyNameLookup, discountRateLookup, discount, tax, pickUpBayLookup);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: in your output you can set a width for the column and thus maintain evenly spaced columns - look here for reference http://stackoverflow.com/q/1809399/3858121

Comment: There's an awful lot of global variables in use — that bodes ill.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1809399/) provided by [Japu_D_Cret](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3858121/japu-d-cret), if you use `%-30s` it will format the string to 30 chars but if the string is longer, it will print all of that...

Try with this:

```
printf_s("%s %s %f %-30.30s %-30.30s %s\n", companyId, companyNameLookup, discountRateLookup, discount, tax, pickUpBayLookup);
```

Using the `.` means it will format the string to exactly 30 chars and the `-` means the string will be left justified (the default is right justified).

EDIT: Adjusted the code to reflect the correction made by @Jonathan Leffler

Comment: Note that `%-.30s` means "left justify; truncate at 30 unless you're done sooner".  If you want the field width to be 30 even if the string is shorter, you need to use `%-30.30s`.  In the general case, you can use `%-*.*s` and provide the same `int` value for each `*` before the string — or, indeed, you can use different values for the two integers if you wish, but quite often you want the same value twice.