# What does the (-) sign do in 'printf("%-x", 2048);'?

Tags: c

I found this question:

What is the output of `printf("%-x", 2048);`?

I know that the `"%x"` is outputting the hexadecimal format of the number, but I can' quite understand what the minus sign does here, since the output is the same for both `printf("%-x", 2048);` and `printf("%x", 2048);`.

Comment: No, but thank you for the link, thats quite helpful

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: This is not a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809399/how-to-format-strings-using-printf-to-get-equal-length-in-the-output). The fact that its answer includes information that answers this question does not mean this question asks the same question as the original, and it in fact does not. Somebody searching for this question is not likely to hit upon that one as relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[std::printf, std::fprintf, std::sprintf, std::snprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf):

> -: the result of the conversion is left-justified within the field (by default it is right-justified)

Comment: And if the field width isn't specified, it has no effect.